# Vagrant host with forwarded port only shows default index.html

Tags: apache, routes, vagrant, portforwarding

I'm setting up a vagrant machine with a forwarded port.

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 4567
```

I'm trying to access the site on port 4567 on my host machine, but I can only get the default /var/www/html/index.html from apache.

I set up in my hosts file /etc/hosts the site pointing to the local ip. And I have my site available and enabled in the apache of my vm to port 80.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue finally. Just in case if someone has the same problem.
I changed in the virtual host configuration from

```
<VirtualHost site1.myserver.com:80>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site1.myserver.com
```